# $(x_n)$, $(y_n) \in l_{\infty}$, $x_n \geq y_n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\Rightarrow f((x_n)) \geq f((y_n))$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let c = $\{$real sequencies convergent$\}$. We define $\overline{f}: c \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, by $\overline{f}((x_n)) = \lim x_n$. We have $\overline{f}$ linear and bounded, for Hahn-Banach, there is a functional bounded and linear $f: l_{\infty} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\parallel f \parallel = \parallel \overline{f} \parallel$ and $f|_{c} = \overline{f}$.

My question: Is true if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_{\infty}$ and $x_n \geq y_n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f((x_n)) \geq f((y_n))$?

If not, how can I show this is false? That is, show that for some $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_{\infty}$, $x_n \geq y_n$, for all extension of $\overline{f}$ we have $f((x_n)) < f((y_n))$.

Comment: $\lVert f\rVert = \lVert \overline{f}\rVert$ forces $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n \leqslant f((x_n)) \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n.$$